# Detecting when a user tries to scroll past the bottom of a component, even if the component doesn't have a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Currently, on the scroll event, I call the below function. If the component has a scroll bar, this works perfectly, and `loadMoreThings()` gets called exactly as expected.

`loadMoreThings()` loads more content into the component, and then the user should be able to scroll to the bottom of the window again, and more content should be loaded etc until there's nothing else to load.

```
updateScroll(instance) {
    let maxHeight = this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight; 
    let value = this.scrollTop;

    let percent = Math.round(100 * ((maxHeight - value) / maxHeight));
    if (percent === 0 && instance.state.isLoaded) {
        instance.loadMoreThings();
    }
    this.scrollTo(0, value);
}
```

However, if the window/device/etc size is tall enough that everything fits in the component, it doesn't overflow, and this function doesn't work, because there wasn't technically any scroll happening at all, even if the user attempts to scroll.

I thought about using the wheel event instead, but it looks like picking a value to call `instance.loadMoreThings()` would be completely arbitrary since the wheel value doesn't really relate back to anything as far as I can tell.

How can I change `updateScroll()` so that even if the initial content doesn't overflow, I can still load some more things when the user tries to scroll past the end of the component?

Comment: `onScroll` returns `e.target` that tells you where the scroll is fired. If you are using iteration to map out your components, then you can check what the iteration value is and add one to it if either the iteration value is currently 1 or if the scroll target is the last object in the mapping.

Comment: @DavidKamer onScroll only triggers an event if there's overflow, which there isn't guaranteed to be

Comment: I meant onWheel, sorry.